# How can I change the width and height of Farbtastic Color Picker Wheel?

Tags: javascript, css, colors, color-picker, farbtastic

On the [Farbastic Github Documentation](https://github.com/mattfarina/farbtastic) it is mentioned that Width and Height of the Farbtastic Color Picker can be modified like this;

```
$(...).farbtastic({ callback: '#color2', width: 150 })
```

But, I am not able to customize the Width and Height of the Farbtastic Color Picker. Here`s my code;

```
colorPickerWheel = $.farbtastic("#colorPickerWheel", { width: 500, height: 500 });
colorPickerWheel.linkTo(pickerUpdate);

function pickerUpdate(color){
    console.log("Color Picker Wheel: " + color);
}
```

Waiting for the response, thanks!

Comment: witch version of jquery did you use ?

Comment: `jquery-2.1.1.min.js`
`jquery-ui-1.11.2/jquery-ui.js`
`jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js`

These three are included in my HTML Page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently `width` and `height` are not picked up if you omit the `callback` parameter (it's probably a bug). However you can workaround it by passing `callback: pickerUpdate` in the options object when initializing it.

```
var colorPickerWheel = $.farbtastic("#colorPickerWheel", {callback: pickerUpdate, width: 500, height: 500});

colorPickerWheel.setColor('#00ffff');

function pickerUpdate(color){
    console.log("Color Picker Wheel: " + color);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s2zhgsbr/1/

Comment: I am using this line of code to get the variable colorPickerWheel 
    `colorPickerWheel = $.farbtastic("#colorPickerWheel");`

And then later setting the Hex value via this line of code
    `colorPickerWheel.setColor("#"+hex);`

But if I use your way, then how can I set the color later dynamically. Please guide. Thanking You!

Comment: Edited my answer to use the other initialization method which allows you to use `setColor()`

Comment: With this syntax my Color Picker is not getting Invoked on my Page, but when reverting my code back `colorPickerWheel.linkTo(pickerUpdate);` as mentioned in the Question above it is getting invoked.
And in either way, Size is not changing :(  Please explain, Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

It is tested and work for me

```
$.farbtastic("#colorPickerWheel", { callback: pickerUpdate,width: 500,  height: 500 });
```

Comment: With this syntax my Color Picker is not getting Invoked on my Page, but when reverting my code back `colorPickerWheel.linkTo(pickerUpdate);` as mentioned in the Question above it is getting invoked.
And in either way, Size is not changing :(  Please explain, Thanks!